# Dynamics Navision 2018 - Insert Sales Order Discount using Web Services

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision, dynamics-nav

I have Navision Dynamics 2018 Update 10 which has Sales Orders exposed as a SOAP web service.

The problem raises when we want to set Invoice Discount which is not available in SO header and it appears in SO Lines as read only property :(

How could I set the invoice discount using the Web Service.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code: You have tu set Invoice_Discount_AmountSpecified false ; if you want to set a number in Invoice_Discount_Amount

```
foreach (var linea in resLineas)
{
    order.SalesLines[contLineas].Invoice_Discount_AmountSpecified = false;
    pedido.SalesLines[contLineas].Invoice_Discount_Amount = 5;
    contLineas++;

}

servicio.Update(ref order);
```